# I can't load song with special characters on Python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to open songs with speacial characters like ó, ú, ... ( Vietnamese characters), but it didn't work :( 
How can i fix this bug? Thanks !!

This code running on Window

```
import pygame

from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()

source = mixer.music.load(f"""{current_database[song-1]['title']}.mp3""".encode('utf8'))

mixer.music.play()
```

Results in:

`pygame.error: Couldn't open 'Có thể là tại sao? - Vũ  (Lyric Video).mp3'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Python get any problem with reading the Vietnamese characters.

Maybe your code got problem when missing some `pygame` modules.

Try this, it works for me:

```py
from pygame import mixer, event, init
init()
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("Anh nhà ở đâu thế - Amee.mp3")
mixer.music.play()
event.wait()
```